# c# by exiting application console close Sparx System instance

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following method for closing the instance of Enterprise Architect Sparx System.

```
  public static  void CloseEAInstance()
  {
        repository.CloseFile();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        repository.Exit();
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
  }
```

When I click on the Close Button, the method above will be called for closing the instance, like this:

```
private void closeDashboardButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EAApi.CloseEAInstance();
    Close();
}
```

How can I invoke this method when the application console gets closed?

---

EDIT `Main` method from comments:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 
try
{
   //Application.Run(new PullPackageForm()); 
   Application.Run(new StarterForm());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: This is a little unclear (to me)...do you have a console application or some UI framework? Did you attach a console to your winforms/wpf/whatever-app? If it's a console app, I guess we need to see at least your `Main` method.

Comment: I have windows forms as dashbord, which is used to start other winsforms. I used the application console
to start the application     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            try
            {
                //Application.Run(new PullPackageForm());
                Application.Run(new StarterForm());


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); ;
            }          
            Console.ReadKey();

Comment: If it's a windows forms app, it does not have a console window (by default). Anyway, why can't you call `CloseEAInstance` after the `Console.ReadKey()`?

Comment: Off topic, but please don't just write `ex.Message` in your error handling, this is really bad. That way you don't know where the exception occured. Print the stack strace!

Comment: Thanks Renee. I already tried that but it doesn't work. I created a console application project and added multiple windows form